# How to generate Doctrine models/classes that extend a custom record class

Tags: php, orm, doctrine

When I use Doctrine to generate classes from Yaml/db each Base class (which includes the table definition) extends the Doctrine_Record class.

Since my app uses a master and (multiple) slave db servers I need to be able to make the Base classes extend my custom record class to force writes to go to the master db server (as described [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/cookbook/1_1/en/master-and-slave-connections)).
However if I change the base class manually I lose it again when I regenerate my classes from Yaml/db using Doctrine.

I need to find a way of telling Doctrine to extend my own Base class, or find a different solution to a master/slave db setup using Doctrine.

Example generated model:

```
abstract class My_Base_User extends Doctrine_Record
{
```

However I need it to be automatically generated as:

```
abstract class My_Base_User extends My_Record
{
```

I am using Doctrine 1.2.1 in a new Zend Framework 1.9.6 application if it makes any difference.

Comment: Related:  if you are trying to do this in a Symfony project, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392713/cant-change-model-builder-options

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Typical, as soon as I ask the question I manage to find the answer. I'm recording it here in case anyone else has the same issue.

You can pass in the parameter 'baseClassName' into the generateModels* methods and Doctrine will use that as the Base record class.

Examples:

```
Doctrine_Core::generateModelsFromDb('models', array('master'), array('generateTableClasses' => true, 'baseClassName' => 'My_Record'));
```

or using Cli:

```
$options['generate_models_options'] = array(
'pearStyle'             => true,
'baseClassPrefix'       => 'My_',
'baseClassName'         => 'My_Record',
'classPrefix'           => '',
'classPrefixFiles'      => false,
'generateTableClasses'  => true,
);

$cli = new Doctrine_Cli($options);
```

Answer (score 1):

Perfect, thanks! This is cool because I grab doctrine options from my application.ini in my Zend Framework project of a similar version (1.9.x). Now I can simply modify the ini to add the baseClassName like so:

```
doctrine.generate_models_options.baseClassName = "BaseRecord"
```

Thanks again for saving me time figuring this out on my own :)