# Can't change model builder options

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

I'm trying to get symfony to use a custom class called `jsDoctrineRecord` instead of `sfDoctrineRecord` for its models. Here's the code for the overriding class:

```
<?php
abstract class jsDoctrineRecord extends sfDoctrineRecord
{
  public function foo()
  {
    echo 'foo';exit;
  }
}
```

Here's what I have in `config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php`, per the instructions [here](http://www.symfony-project.org/doctrine/1_2/en/03-Configuration#chapter_03_configuring_model_building):

```
<?php

require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../lib/vendor/symfony/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php';
sfCoreAutoload::register();

class ProjectConfiguration extends sfProjectConfiguration
{
  public function setup()
  {
    $this->enablePlugins('sfDoctrinePlugin');
    $this->enablePlugins('sfDoctrineGuardPlugin');
    $this->enablePlugins('jsDoctrineSchemaOverriderPlugin');
  }

  public function configureDoctrine(Doctrine_Manager $manager)
  {
    $options = array('baseClassName' => 'jsDoctrineRecord');
    sfConfig::set('doctrine_model_builder_options', $options);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. My models continue to inherit from `sfDoctrineRecord` instead of `jsDoctrineRecord`. The `foo()` method is not recognized. I still have the problem when I clear my cache.

I'm pretty sure I'm following the instructions right, so what could be going wrong?

Comment: Just to make sure... you have rebuilt the models, right? (doctrine:build-model)

Comment: No, I hadn't done that. I just did that and now it works. Thanks! If you want to put that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to rebuild the model so that the Base record classes extend your new record class. Run doctrine:build-model.

Answer (score 4):

Im not sure whay thats not working as its still there for BC, but after looking at the sfDoctrinePlugin it looks like the proper way to handle this is with a [symfony event listener](http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/15-Events#chapter_15_sub_doctrine_filter_model_builder_options) (see lines 83 - 89 of `SF_LIB_DIR/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/config/sfDoctrinePluginConfiguration.class.php`):

in projectConfiguration:

```
public function setup()
{
   $this->enablePlugins('sfDoctrinePlugin');
   $this->enablePlugins('sfDoctrineGuardPlugin');
   $this->enablePlugins('jsDoctrineSchemaOverriderPlugin');

   $this->dispatcher->connect(
     'doctrine.filter_model_builder_options', 
     array($this, 'configureDoctrineBuildOptions')
   );
}

public function configureDoctrineBuildOptions(sfEvent $event, $options)
{
   $options['baseClassName'] = 'jsDoctrineRecord';

   return $options;
}
```

Give that a shot and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks for posting the source location.  Muy helpful!  What is "BC" in this context?

Comment: @Phoneix: BC = Backwards Compatibility.